# error in first step of of Ubuntu Deb Pack Installation

Tags: software-installation

When I copied the first line of the Ubuntu Deb Pack Installation of 14.04 LTS, which is:

```
VERS=$(lsb_release ‐cs) 
sudo sh ‐c "echo deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $VERS main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list
```

I get this error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open ‐c.
```

Please explain why I am getting this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Here is the explanation:**

Your `‐` isn't really a `-`, *although they look exactly the same!* The one in your example is a UNICODE U+2010 whereas what you need is a UNICODE U+0045 (ASCII 45).

*Here is a test with your `‐`:*

```
$ echo "‐" > test
$ hexdump test 
0000000 80e2 0a90
```

*And here is the regular `-`:*

```
$ echo "-" > test
$ hexdump test1
0000000 0a2d
```

---

**This command works:**

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list'
```

or the longer version:

```
VERS=$(lsb_release -cs)
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $VERS main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list'
```

Comment: Note: To paste into the terminal you need to do CTRL+SHIFT+C/V.

Comment: Sir, when I copy and paste above given two codes in my terminal, I do not get the message -  'sh: 0: Can't open ‐c' . But, on writing either of the above two codes, terminal window is not performing any action. Please explain why terminal window is not taking any action for either of the above two codes which you have suggested and also suggest what step should I take next?

Comment: Use this command as I wrote: `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openfoam.list'`. It works, I tested it several times.